# Need help positioning in regex

Tags: regex, google-visualization

I have an array of data which I would like to pass in Google Charts. But the problem is like in Google Chart we can use the format which I need.

In regex how to fix a starting position in an array for replacing content? Say, for example I have some data, like `["JAN","1088626"],["FEB","1478093"]`.

I need to replace the double quotes only for the numbers. I want the output to be like `["JAN",1088626],["FEB",1478093]`.

I have checked with `someStr.replace(/['"]+/g, '')` but it rips all double quotes.

Comment: What is the language, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: i have an array of data which i would like to pass in google charts.But the problem is like in google chart we can use the format which i need.

Comment: I have checked with someStr.replace(/['"]+/g, '') but it rips all double quotes.

Comment: Try [`(["'])(\d+)\1`](https://regex101.com/r/fL3mE4/1).

Comment: hi stribizhev,Thank you so much you make my day friend.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer once you come here again.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(["'])(\d+)\1
```

The regex ([see its demo here](https://regex101.com/r/fL3mE4/1)) matches:

- `(["'])` - either a double or a single quote and puts that symbol into Group 1
- `(\d+)` - 1 or more digits and puts that value into Group 2
- `\1` - matches the same symbol that is inside Group 1